# How to display a curved video with aframe

Tags: aframe

I've tried `<a-videosphere>` and `<a-video>` and they are great.

But if i use a "normal" video, it is incredibly stretched with `a-videosphere` and just flat with `a-video`.

But is there a way for the video to be curved around the user ?

Just like if the user was inside a cylinder : similar to `a-curvedimage` but for a video.

EDIT (problem with `a-curvedimage` and `src`) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can display a video as a texture on any geometry by using the `src` attribute:

```
<a-box src="#video"></a-box>
<a-curvedimage src="#video"></a-curvedimage>
<a-torus-knot src="#video"></a-torus-knot>
```

remixed example glitch [here](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-vid-on-primitives).

---

If you're asking if you can make a normal video equirectangular, without earlier preparation, or some image manipulation library, `aframe` won't do it for you.

Comment: thank for the answer !! by using curvedimage everything is working but the image is very distorded (added image on original post), i don't understand why : `<a-curvedimage src="#video" height="9" position="0 0 0" radius="8" theta-length="72" rotation="0 180 0"></a-curvedimage>` Video is mp4

Comment: What are the video dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with `a-curvedimage` and the `src` attribute, and solved it by using the generic `a-entity` element instead, recreating the open-ended, double-sided cylinder of the `a-curvedimage` element.

Example for a 1280x720 video:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="myvideo" preload="auto" src="/path/to/video.mp4" width="1280" height="720" autoplay="true" loop="true" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline=""></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity material="shader: flat; side: double; src: #myvideo" geometry="primitive: cylinder; radius: 5; height: 3.6815; open-ended: true; theta-start: 142.5; theta-length: 75; position="0 1.5 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="-1 1 1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Additional Info:
Stefie has a [great calculator](https://stefie.github.io/aframe-curvedimage-calculator/) for the attributes of different dimensions for curved images and videos.

Edit: Video was inverted on the X-Axis to the user, so added a scale attribute with -1 for the X-Axis.